# nodejs promise better way to handle errors happening in promise implementation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception, try-catch, es6-promise

This is probably asked many times but I couldn't find a proper example for my solution. Here is the main example where I am returning a promise and I mocked the response body to make it fail. I am trying to handle the exception to catch it and log it properly.

```
const request = require('request');

var url = "https://bittrex.com/Api/v2.0/pub/market/GetTicks?marketName=BTC-STRAT&tickInterval=hour";

function requestMarketData() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request(url, function(err, res, body) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return reject(err);
            }
            console.log("GET: " + url);
            var result = JSON.parse("<HTML>"); // make JSON.parse fail
            return resolve(result);
        });
    });
}

async function getMarketData() {
    var result = await requestMarketData();
}

getMarketData();
```

First way I am trying to handle it;

```
async function getMarketData() {
    try {
        var result = await requestMarketData();
    } catch(err) {
        console.log("Failed result: " + err);
    }
}
```

which didn't work which is expected because of asynchronous work.

Second way by appending catch handler for the returned promise;

```
function requestMarketData() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request(url, function(err, res, body) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return reject(err);
            }
            console.log("GET: " + url);
            var result = JSON.parse("<HTML>"); // make JSON.parse fail
            return resolve(result);
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log("Failed result: " + err);
    });
}
```

didn't work as well.

Third way;

```
function requestMarketData() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request(url, function(err, res, body) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return reject(err);
            }
            console.log("GET: " + url);
            var result = [];
            try {
                result = JSON.parse("<HTML>"); // make JSON.parse fail
            } catch(err) {
                result = [{foo: "bar"}];
                return reject(result);
            }
            return resolve(result);
        });
    });
}
```

Which finally worked. However, my question is there a better way to handle these kind of errors outside from promise implementation?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: *“which didn't work which is expected because of asynchronous work.”* That isn’t why it’s expected. `await`ing a rejected promise should throw an error you can catch with `try`. The issue is that failed parsing doesn’t cause a rejected promise.

Comment: @Ry thanks for response I am kinda new for nodejs. However, if that is true how come I am not able to catch the error? And does promises return reject when there is an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `requestMarketData` function needs to cause the promise to be rejected when JSON parsing fails. Right now, it throws an error at `JSON.parse`, and there’s nothing to catch it (the `Promise` constructor only catches errors thrown synchronously inside it). You *can* catch it yourself:

```
function requestMarketData() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request(url, function(err, res, body) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return reject(err);
            }
            console.log("GET: " + url);

            var result;

            try {
                result = JSON.parse("<HTML>"); // make JSON.parse fail
            } catch (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }

            return resolve(result);
        });
    });
}
```

but [`Promise#then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) will also catch it for you:

```
function requestMarketData() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request(url, function(err, res, body) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return reject(err);
            }

            console.log("GET: " + url);
            return resolve(body);
        });
    }).then(JSON.parse);
}
```

Equivalently, with an async function:

```
function requestMarketData() {
    let body = await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request(url, function(err, res, body) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return reject(err);
            }

            console.log("GET: " + url);
            return resolve(body);
        });
    });

    return JSON.parse(body);
}
```

Comment: wow both ways look much way cleaner. Do I need to verify if `body` is an error in the first approach? Or putting `.catch()` after `then` should be enough?

Comment: @quartaela: You don’t need to do either. `.then()` converts a thrown error into a *rejected* promise, so your `getMarketData` with the `try` will catch it (because `await` converts rejected promises back into thrown errors).

Comment: Thanks a lot Ry! I definitely got it. One last question if you don't mind. when you send `JSON.parse` how I can edit the object returned from it inside the `then` block. Or is there a way to do that? Say I want to reach a field like `body.result`

Comment: @quartaela: You can add another `.then(data => data.result)` to transform the result of the first `.then`.